# Constructing a falsifying interpretation to $\forall x[\exists y[Ryx]] : \exists y[\forall x[Ryx]]$ from a target set of truth-values

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

Question 10 of Exercise 7.3 of Tomassi's *Logic* (p. 372) asks you to test the following sequent for validity: $$\forall x[\exists y[Ryx]] : \exists y[\forall x[Ryx]]$$

I followed his flowchart on p. 344 and produced the following tree:

$\begin{array}{111}&1. &\forall x[\exists y[Ryx]] &\text{Premise}\\
&2. &\lnot\exists y[\forall x[Ryx]] &\text{Negated conclusion}\\
&3. &\forall y[\lnot\forall x[Ryx]] &\text{2 Quantifier equivalence}\\
&4. &\forall y[\exists x[\lnot Ryx]] &\text{3 Quantifier equivalence}\\
&5. &\exists y[Rya] &\text{1 UIN}\\
&6. &\exists x[\lnot Rax] &\text{4 UIN}\\
&7. &Rba &\text{5 EIN}\\
&8. &\lnot Rac &\text{6 EIN}\\
\end{array}$

At this point, all the formulas are developed and there's no contradiction, so the sequent is invalid. This is where I'm having trouble; as far as I understand it, the target set of truth-values (TST) that the tree is suggesting is one where $Rba$ is true and $Rac$ is false. But the following interpretation is not a counterexample, since the premise isn't true:
$$\mathbf D:\{0,1,2\}\\R:\{<1,0>\}\\a: 0\\b: 1\\c: 2$$

I guess I'm doing something wrong in constructing a falsifying interpretation from the TST, but I'm not sure what. For all the previous questions, where I was dealing only with monadic predicates rather than relations, I've simply had the domain consist of as many elements as there are names, assigned the elements to the names, and filled out the extensions of the predicates as suggested by the TST, but here that doesn't seem to be working. Can someone explain where I'm going wrong, and what the strategy for constructing falsifying interpretations from TSTs should be when you're dealing with relations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At lines 7 and 8 you have introduced new names that are now available to instantiate the universal quantifiers at lines 1 and 4 … so not all formulas are “developed” as far as possible ….

So you’ll now get further lines starting with $\exists yRyb$, … and then you’ll need to instantiate that with a further new name …

Yes, this way you’ll get an infinite unclosed tableaux but if done systematically you can read off an infinite-domain model which makes the premises true and conclusion false.

(Of course, using brute force like this gives you a counter model infinitely bigger than necessary … you should immediately be able to spot a two-object model that does the trick!)

Comment: Depending on your definitions (mostly depending on whether your formulation of first-order logic allows an empty domain at all), an empty model could also be considered to refute the sequent.

Comment: @DanielSchepler Indeed, and of course if we allow empty domains, as in Hodges version of a tableaux system, the tree can't get started as you can only instantiate universals with a name already on a branch. Which instantly shows that the argument is invalid (allowing empty domains). But that's not Tomassi's more conventional system  as I recall.

Comment: Ah, thank you, I hadn't come across this situation yet where new names are introduced so you need to go back to universal quantifiers that you've already developed. Embarrassed that I missed this!